# Testing the SQL Server connection

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using Netbeans( I have jar file in my library) to connect to SQL Server and wondering why nothing is happening. I am can see the following message printing on my screen `Loading the Driver for SQL Server at xx.xx.x.xxx` and nothing happens after that:

I am also trying to test whether the connection is null or not but for some reason `System.out.println("Connection Successful !");` is not printing anything and hence I suspect it's not getting connected. Could anyone please see what's going on here:

My code is here:

```
        try {
                String QueryStringGlobalAlertLogs = "";

                 try{

                      System.out.println("Loading the Driver for SQL Server at xx.xx.x.xxx");    
                      Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                     }
                catch(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e){
                return 0;   
                     }

                connRemoteforGlobal = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xxx;database‌​Name=Alerts",RemoteSQLServerUser,RemoteSQLServerPass);


                if(connRemoteforGlobal != null)
                {
                   System.out.println("Connection Successful !");
                 }



                 QueryStringGlobalAlertLogs =  // My INSERT Query here
            }// End of first try
     catch(SQLException ex2){

            ex2.printStackTrace();
           System.out.println("Error Trace in Connection : " + ex2.getMessage());
                            }
```

Comment: `catch() { return 0 }`? perhaps you should be actually DOING something with exceptions instead of trying to make this code act like VB's `on error resume next`.

Comment: What would you recommend then? When I write false it throws error. Do you think that could be the issue?

Comment: At least try a `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` to get a message for debugging and not just ignore the exception.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Tried `System.out.println(e.getMessage());` and also `e.printStackTrace();` but there was no change.

Answer (score 0):

You must catching `Class.forName` and `getConnection` together.
try this:

```
    try{
       Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xxx;database‌Name=Alerts",RemoteSQLServerUser,RemoteSQLServerPass);
    }catch(SQLException e1){
       // handle error
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e2){
       // handle error
    }
```

Comment: I did that but still no clue why it is not moving forward. I deliberately commented out `Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");` and got the error message "No Suitable Driver found" in the stack trace, so the control is for sure going over there but still why it's not moving forward, I am unable to figure out. Is there any other way to test what's going wrong ?

Comment: Does my connection string looks good: `jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.x.xxx;database‌​Name=Alerts",RemoteSQLServerUser,RemoteSQLServerPass` ?